# Get-ChildItem -Filter parameter not working as expected on Windows PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Run `Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter '*.sql'` on folders with two files: `001.sql_bk` and `010.sql`, and the output is as below. File `001.sql_bk` is not expected in output.

```
...
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        2023/02/09     11:09            141 001.sql_bk
-a----        2023/02/09     11:14            187 010.sql
```

The Version of Windows PowerShell is:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.2364
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.2364
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

On PowerShell 7.3, the output is as expected:

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a---          2023/02/09    11:14            187 010.sql
```

Comment: this is a bug in dotnet framework, you would see the same if you attempt to call the api: `(gi .).EnumerateFiles('*.sql')` in cases like this you can use `-Include`: `gci .\* -include *.txt`

Comment: @Santiago, it's not a bug per se, but "legacy quirks" for the sake of backward compatibility, some of which still affect PowerShell Core as well. Indeed, letting PowerShell perform the wildcard matching avoids the problem.